# Is VMware aware of Linux memory disk caching?

Tags: linux, memory, virtual-machine, vmware, cache

In my [VMware](https://www.vmware.com/) environment a VM is marked as "*Stressed*" by memory because it constantly demands about 75% of total RAM.

It is a Debian 9 VM, so I connected with SSH several times to investigate this issue; I noticed that `free` command output on average says that only about 840MB RAM out of 2 GB total are used, another 1GB is used for buff/cache.

As far as I know, Linux kernel can reclaim buff/cached RAM if it needs more memory: so, does [VMware vSphere](https://www.vmware.com/products/vsphere.html) know about this mechanism, or that VM has some wrong configuration?

Edit: here is a typical output of `free -h` command from that VM:

```
               total       used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:           2.0G        927M         76M        156M        1.0G        772M
Swap:          2.0G        293M        1.7G
```

Comment: I do not understand the downvote!

Comment: According to this [answer](https://serverfault.com/a/85481) about Understanding the `free` output, _A Linux system is really low on memory if the free value in -/+ buffers/cache: line gets low._. Please [edit] your question adding a typical output... It's possible some application in the VM is actually caching a lot...

Comment: Did you install the VMware tools on that machine?

Comment: @Seth yes, open-vm-tools are installed.

Comment: @J.B. It's quite a normal use of memory... if up it has to have some memory use... :-)  you [can see](https://www.reddit.com/r/linux/comments/5l39tz/linux_distros_ram_consumption_comparison_updated/) to have an idea, BTW it depends on the Desktop Environment too and if some services are up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In short, no, VMWare does not know (or care) what a guest is using ram for, only that its using it. The RAM is in use by the guest, even if its being used for somthing the guest could do without if it choose to.

VMWare is only concerned with the amount of RAM available to guests in its totality, especially how much is available for other guests (which is critical when overbooking the hosts RAM). Any Caching/buffering/swapping the guest chooses to perform (or not) is its business, so if you want to configure that behavior, you do it in the guest. VMWare does not try to modify the memory management practices of the guest at all.

If you want VMWare to ignore the RAM usage by that box, I recommend you reconfigure the alerts for it.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the VMware balloon driver is relevant here. Should the hypervisor run low on RAM due to all these VMs using RAM just for disk cache, the vmware tools balloon driver will create demand for RAM *within* the VM itself, forcing the VM OS to reduce the amount of RAM it uses for caching, and freeing up this RAM for the hypervisor to use elsewhere.